# how can I make the video part of this project work?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make the code on the following page : https://github.com/gnuns/omigo work on my computer locally, and the text-messaging part works, but the video part doesn't.

I Have tried to manipulate the code my self, but i didn't find the solution yet, someone talled me that the code is depreciated, so i tried to learn about the webrtc, but only found old books.

there is no error message, just the browser ask for the permission to use the micro and webcam, and then nothing.

Comment: Hi Alan, your question needs to be more specific. It's too broad currently and it's not very clear of what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, what do you think I should add to be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the security enforced by browser when the application tries to use media devices.
see this link for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your help, i am going to visit this site to resolve my problem

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the link but I didn’t suceed yet, which part of the link is the most important according to my need ?